# Захват звука с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, ffmpeg, видео, запись

Каким образом можно записать звук с самого компьютера (c колонок) с помощью программы ffmpeg? Вообще мне нужно записывать скринкасты со всеми звуками. Есть команда, которая записывает видео с экрана в хорошим качеством со звуком с микрофона:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -ab 320k -acodec mp3 -f x11grab -s 854x480 -r 25 -i :0.0+261,167 -vcodec mpeg2video -sameq output.mpg
```

Но записывает ТОЛЬКО микрофон. А мне нужен и звук с самого компьютера. Помогите, пожалуйста... Буду очень благодарен.

P.S.1 Гуглил

P.S.2 Много гуглил

P.S.3 Перепробовал много всякого, и никакого результата

P.S.4 ОС -- Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -ab 320k -acodec mp3 output.mp3
```

или

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -ab 320k output.mka
```

или еще как-нибудь так (мало пробовал)

Answer (score 0):

Слишком толсто) Попробуйте [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)

А если вдруг будут проблемы со звуком то [RTFM](http://thexnews.com/ubuntu/recordMyDesktop%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC.html)

Comment: Он у меня как-то криво работает. Через ffmpeg куда проще все.

Comment: Ну вы все правильно делаете, поставьте pavucontrol , а далее как по второй ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Записываю например так:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor outf.mp3
```

Источник звука, предназначенный именно для "записи с колонок", искать так:

```
pacmd list-sources | grep 'monitor>'
```

OS - Debian 9

Comment: Интересно как. Вопросу уже 4 года)
Вышел OBS. С ним намного стало все проще.  В любом случае, спасибо за ответ)